# Mixpanel delete user data using api

Tags: mixpanel

I want to delete all the data created for a user on mix panel . I have tried to use mixpanel engage api to delete the profile but i can still see the profile . Only profile properties is getting cleared .

curl --request POST 
--url 'https://api.mixpanel.com/engage#profile-delete' 
--header 'Accept: text/plain' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--data 'data={
"$token": "YOUR_PROJECT_TOKEN",
"$distinct_id": "13793",
"$delete": "",
"$ignore_alias": false
}
'

What is $delete field used for (didn't find anything in the mixpanel documentation)

How can i delete everything created for a user via api (profile , event and properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the data from mixpanel using the api. Instead refer to https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000881023-Export-or-Delete-End-User-Data

If you only need to hide the data (not applicable if you for example need to delete it for GDPR reasons), you can overwrite it using the the `import` api, and add a field to it that you then filter out (i.e. `deleted`=`true`).

> Events with identical values for (event, time, distinct_id, $insert_id) are considered duplicates and only one of them will be surfaced in queries.

Have a look at https://developer.mixpanel.com/reference/import-events to use this solution.